# Runtime Error Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

Basically am trying to copy a sheet from one workbook to another. While doing that i get an error called subscript out of range.

```
Sub cp()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
'Target workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Desktop:\Book2.xlsb")
'Source workbook
For Each ws In Workbooks("Desktop:\Book1.xlsb")
ws.copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line raises the error? `Set wb = ...`?

Comment: Subscript out of range would indicate you're referring to a Workbook (by name) which doesn't exist in the Workbooks collection.

Comment: Yes it shows error in Set wb. But the workbook is in my Desktop folder

Comment: The book needs to be opened, or the code can't find it.

Comment: OK. Then the workbook you're referencing is *not already open*, so you will get the error.

Comment: Are you sure that's a *valid* file path? If so, can you execute `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Desktop:\Book2.xlsb")`

Comment: Its already opened. Yes path is correct.

Comment: If it's already open, then you don't use the path, just `Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsb")`

Comment: Yes removed. Now it shows object doesnot support this property or method.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is already open, then just do:

```
Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsb")
```

And likewise,

```
For each ws in Workbooks("Book1.xlsb").Worksheets
```

Note also you need to indicate the `.Worksheets` collection in the above statement. `For each ws in Workbooks("Book1.xlsb")` will not work, even though a workbook contains worksheets, there is no implied iteration like this, you need to specify which collection you're looping over.